# Image disappears when I create a .ipa or binaries for an iPhone project

Tags: ios, xcode, uiimage, ios5, testflight

I'm using a simple image in my xcode project.

With the normal screen version (and the retina Display version '@2x.png'
actually over the retina display) everything is fine.

```
UIImage * image1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.png"];
```

Then I'm using that image over a button. The image appears when I test with xcode over the simulator, or the iPhone 3g and other devices. But when I test my app over testflight, or from the app store, the image disappears.

I have tried:

- Clean the whole project
- Replace the image
- Change the code to implement that image in a different way
- Using a different image
- Restore in normal, recovery mode and dfu mode the not retina display devices
- Pray =(

Anyone have an idea how I can fix this ?

Comment: The reason is XCode thinks that those images are not under version control.. weird.

Answer (score 2):

You probably have already done this, but have you checked your target>Build Phases to make sure in "Copy Bundle Resources" that image is actually being copied?

Comment: actually the image is over there

Answer (score 2):

Probably the problem is that the image is being referenced by a **weak** pointer when it should be **strong**. In **release** mode, some optimisations are done and the memory is released more aggressively than in **debug** mode, and that's why your problem only arises once you have archived the project for distribution on TestFlight or the AppStore (built in release mode)...

Answer (score 0):

Is the image included in your compile sources (compile bundle resources) ?

[image]

Comment: nop, it's not include, I need include all the image over that option, for what I need include over there ? Thanks for the answer :)

Comment: Then you need to add it. Either drag&drop it from your xCode project, or click the + sign at the bottom of the copy bundle resources window and add it to the list...

Comment: the image is over there, but the bug still happen in the same way!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is stupid but have you tried using a JPG instead of a PNG? Just to discard the possibility that the PNG optimizer messes up something...